# Possible ways to handle pdf files that i have in asset folders. Because of these files application size increases to 1GB. How can i manage these pdf's

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on Flutter. I have a project for which I stored many of the books in the assets folder. Because of this, my application size has increased. How can I manage them? Can anyone guide me with the code? If I handle them through local storage, is it really helpful for me? Also, I need code to handle it.

I tried to put them in local storage, but in my case, the code is not working properly, and I'm unable to resolve the problem that I had.